# Returning first occurrence index of a number in a list

Tags: python

I have a bunch of csv files containing time data and numbers, I wrote a function to return the first occurrence of a number below a threshold (x) this way :

```
def bounce(tickList,x):
    n = 0
    for i in tickList:
        if float(i[1]) < x:
            return n
            break
        n += 1
```

except that when I loop the execution of the bounce function this way :

```
for i in os.listdir(resultDir):

    if "csv" in i:
        csvFile = resultDir+i
        print csvFile
        with open(csvFile, 'rb') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            tickList = []
            for line in reader:
                tickList.append(line)

        print bounce(tickList,5)
```

it keeps on returning zero (even though the first value is **above** the threshold ) .

Where am I going wrong ?

---

*Here is a sample of one of the csv files :*

```
1373289767.454535,9.9
1373289769.728528,9.9
1373289771.817576,9.9
1373289773.813036,11.7
1373289775.810985,11.7
1373289777.769641,11.7
1373289779.783134,12.2
1373289781.774255,11.8
1373289783.799892,12.0
1373289785.812967,11.4
1373289787.816991,11.4
1373289789.790835,11.3
1373289791.811245,10.9
1373289793.880356,10.8
1373289795.846866,10.7
1373289797.847552,10.6
1373289799.858929,10.6
```

Thanks in advance .

**EDIT** after comments

Here is the new function:

```
def bounce(tickList,x):
    n = 0
    for i in tickList:
        if float(i[1]) < x:
            return n 
        n += 1
```

if I print *float(i[1])* it returns the right numbers so it is calling the right files .

**SECOND EDIT**

found the problem, the "level" I was feeding it was in fact a **str** and not an **int**, thanks for everybody who had a look and helped .

Comment: I am not sure if the identation in the provided example is correct, but what is that `break` doing after a `return n` statement?

Comment: What does it show if you print float(i[1])?

Comment: Yep, break statement doesn't seem to help.....

Comment: Your function returns `None` for the provided sample data for me. As provided here, **it works for me**.

Comment: yes is likely coming from the break statement but I want the execution of the function to stop after it finds the first occurrence

Comment: @Fingertwist: No `break` needed, the `return` ends the function *and* the loop.

Comment: `return` stops the function. What did you think would happen if you didn't `break`?

Comment: After you call `return`, you exit the function, so there is no need for the `break` afterwards.

Comment: `return` already stops execution. That `break` is never executed. Are you sure that `print csvFile` prints the correct path on every iteration (are all the path-separating slashes in there?)?

Comment: You may want to learn about `enumerate()`, and your `tickList` can be defined as `tickList = list(reader)`; no explicit loop required.

Comment: Yes, but break always stops the routine after the first entry.

Comment: I though that I would use a break because I just wanted to return the first occurence if I didn't I thought that I would return the last one .

Comment: getting rid of the "break" doesn't seem to change things unfortunately

Comment: What if there is no such value? You fall off the end of your `bounce` function without a return statement.

Comment: @Fingertwist: No, it doesn't. It was entirely redundant. It could have caused things to behave badly if the indentation was not correct. Are you sure the `n += 1` line is indented properly?

Comment: `return` doesn't mean "remember to return this when I'm done with the function"; it means "stop, right now, and return".

Comment: @JoshG79: In which case `None` would be printed, not 0.

Comment: Ok, got rid of the break statement ! :)

Comment: @Fingertwist: If the `n += 1` line is not properly indented (for example, because you mixed tabs and spaces), then `n` will remain at 0 forever and not be incremented.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: that is a VERY astute observation. So true, so cryptic to find and never thought of first

Comment: @inspectorG4dget yes,and then return its index in the list

Comment: sorry, I was mistaken about how csv works. I'm inclined to agree with @MartijnPieters now. I have a feeling that you're mixing tabs and spaces

Comment: Try `python -m pdb script.py`. Then step through and see where the function is returning.

Comment: Print n to make sure its advancing properly.

Answer (score 2):

I *strongly* suspect that your indentation is incorrect, and by mixing spaces and tabs Python interprets your method as:

```
def bounce(tickList,x):
    n = 0
    for i in tickList:
        if float(i[1]) < x:
            return n
            break
    n += 1
```

where `n += 1` is left *outside* the loop and never increments `n`. Alternatively, `n += 1` could be indented *too far*:

```
def bounce(tickList,x):
    n = 0
    for i in tickList:
        if float(i[1]) < x:
            return n
            break
            n += 1
```

Your function would return `0` for any case where there is a row with `float(i[1])` below `x`.

You can test for such problems by running your script with `python -tt scriptname.py`, where `-tt` tells python to look for inconsistent use of tabs and spaces and raise an error if it finds such problems.

You can simplify your code by using `enumerate()`, and inlining the test, exiting reading the file *early*:

```
for fname in os.listdir(resultDir):
    if "csv" in fname:
        csvFile = os.path.join(resultDir, fname)
        print csvFile
        with open(csvFile, 'rb') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for i, row in enumerate(reader)
                if float(row[1]) < 5:
                    print i
                    break    # exit for loop, continue with next file
```

The inner `for` loop can be simplified down further by using `next()` and an generator expression:

```
with open(csvFile, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    print next((i for i, r in enumerate(reader) if float(r[1]) < 5), 'Not found')
```

as `next()` *stops looping* once a result has been found.

Comment: Side gripe - why is `-tt` not the default!? Mixing tabs and spaces in a python program is a recipe for disaster and is easily avoidable

Comment: @JoshG79: Because mixing tabs and spaces *can* be done if done carefully. But even with a good IDE that is hard and tricky and should be avoided really. Legacy code should not break because suddenly Python decides that mixing is no longer allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You've sad you need a value **below** threshold and that's exactly what in your code. But after you are expecting value **above** threshold. Change `bounce()` or threshold ot test data:)

```
import csv

def bounce(tickList,x):
    n = 0
    for i in tickList:
        #print float(i[1])
        if float(i[1]) > x:
            return n
        n += 1

csvFile = 'test.csv'
print csvFile
tickList = []
with open(csvFile, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in reader:
        tickList.append(line)

print bounce(tickList,5)
```

This code prints `0`.

Comment: doing this returns "None"

Comment: Oh, I've moved `tickList = []` out of `with`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def bounce(tickList,x):
    n = 0
    for i in tickList:
        if float(i[1]) < x:
            return n  # return float(i[1)
            n += 1
    return None
```

something like this???

Comment: This doesn't return the index. Nor does it explain the error the OP is seeing.

Comment: He wanted the first occurrence of a number.  It didn't sound like an index (but his code showed that, obviously).

Comment: No, I'm just an idiot, don't assume the OP is... :)  Sounds like a str vs. int issue.

Comment: No, it's not a str vs int issue, because the OP is explicitly converting the CSV data to float first.

Comment: Indeed; as so often is the case, the simplified version of the code made assumptions into constants that did not reflect reality. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced you need the entire data into memory, so maybe something as simple as:

```
reader = enumerate(csv.reader(f))
idx, row = next((r for r in reader if float(r[1][1]) < 5), (None, None))
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are not mixing spaces and tabs in the identation.

This works as expected for me (I edited the original function to return both the index and the element value).

```
def bounce(tickList,x):
    n = 0
    for i in tickList:
        if float(i[1]) < x:
            return (n, i[1])
        n += 1
```